# Dialog closes twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the code:

```
var timer;

$('#phone_number').click(function(){
    $("#phone_dialog").dialog('open');
    timer = setTimeout(function(){ phone_close() },10000);
});

$('#phone_dialog').click(function(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
phone_close();
});

function phone_close(){
$('#phone_dialog').dialog('close');
};
```

The idea is that the user clicks `phone_number` to open the dialog.  The user can click to close the  dialog, but if he fails to do so it disappears after 10 seconds, by `setTimer()`.

What happens in practice, however, is that the `clearTimeout(timer)` doesn't seem to stop the timer.  The user can click to close after say 2 seconds.  The dialog then [re-opens and] closes on the 10th second, despite the presence of the `clearTimeout` in the click function.

Comment: Why is the dialog reopening? I suspect that's your problem -- something is running the handler that opens the dialog again, which starts a new timer.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: my guess is you have the elements nested so both clicks fire. event.stopPropagation()

Comment: can you share the relevant html - if possible create a [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/HZBmS/5/)

Comment: Could you edit [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FloydPink/9L7E6/) and try to reproduce the issue there?

Comment: I have created a [JsFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HZBmS/7/) of your problem. No problem at all ... is this what you want ? If not edit this Fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use isOpen to check whether the dialog is already closed or not

```
function phone_close(){
     if($("#phone_dialog").dialog( "isOpen" )
     {
          $('#phone_dialog').dialog('close');
     }
};
```

Comment: "isOpen" saves the day.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change first function like this:

```
$('#phone_number').click(function(){
    $("#phone_dialog").dialog('open');
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function(){ phone_close() },10000);
});
```